# Relationship between Fetching a Collection and Parsing its Associated Model

Tags: json, backbone.js

When one calls `fetch()` on a BackboneJS collection, why and how does `parse()` in the model also get called? I basically have **Board** collection and model, and also **List** collection and model. A **List** belongs-to a **Board**. I want to send the **List** down as JSON data with a **Board** model (when a "GET" request is called, for instance); however, I do NOT want to send the **List** down as JSON data when the collection is fetched.

My understanding was that calling fetch on a collection goes through the following steps (never going through the model, let alone the `parse()` on the model):

> *`index` action in controller -> sends JSON/data to Backbone -> the collection receives this data and stores it*

I have a collection of boards in that has an associated model:

**Board** **Collection**:

```
TrelloClone.Collections.Boards = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/boards',

  model: TrelloClone.Models.Board
});

TrelloClone.Collections.boards = new TrelloClone.Collections.Boards();
```

**Board** **Model**:

```
TrelloClone.Models.Board = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/api/boards',

  lists: function() {
    if(!this._lists) {
        this._lists = new TrelloClone.Collections.Lists([], {board: this});
    }
    return this._lists;
  },

  parse: function(response) {
    console.log("parsing");
    if(response.lists) {
        console.log("inside lists");
        this.lists().set(response.lists);
        delete response.lists;
    }
  }
});
```

Essentially, for a particular **Board** model, I send back "lists" with that board:

```
#in the boards controller
def show
  @board = Board.includes(:members, lists: :cards).find(params[:id])

  if @board.is_member?(current_user)
    render :show
  else
    render json: ["You aren't a member of this board"], status: 403
  end
end

...

#in the JBuilder file...
json.extract! @board, :title

json.lists @board.lists do |list|
    json.extract! list, :title, :ord 

    json.cards list.cards do |card|
        json.extract! card, :title, :done
    end
end
```

For a **Board** collection, on the other hand, I do not send back the "list":

```
def index
  @boards = current_user.boards
  render json: @boards
end
```

The problem with my above implementation is that when I `fetch()` the **Board** collection, the attributes of each Board object are not sent over. But when I comment out the `parse()` function, everything works fine.

EDIT:
I figured out why I wasn't getting data on a collection fetch. I forgot to `return response` at the end of the `parse` function. It'd be nice if someone could clarify what exactly are the sequence of steps that occur when a collection is fetched (where the parsing happens in this sequence). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the annotated source of [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).

When the data is fetched Backbone either sets `{reset: false}` or resets `{reset: true}` the collection values. Then it calls your success callback and finally triggers `sync`:

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-133

In `collection.set` you can see exactly when the `model.parse` method is called and why you have to return the response:

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-109